# Finding 1907 New York City arraignment results?

Tags: united-states, new-york-city, 1900s-decade, court-records

In searching my great grandfather, I came across an article in The Brooklyn Daily Eagle (6/16/1907) of the arrest of a man with the same name (Harry Farson - not sure if they are one in the same yet, or not). He was arraigned in the Harlem Police Court on 6/15/1907, but, I cannot find ANY information regarding the case after that. I don't know if he was sent to jail. My great grandfather was on the [1905 census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:9Q97-YSRS-FJX?mode=g&i=16&cc=1463113) with my great grandmother, Minetta, but, not on the 1910 census - so, I am wondering if the man arraigned is my great grandfather, and ended up in jail.

Any advice on where I can find the answer?

His parents are George & Mary, and he had a brother William. 1905 was the year my grandmother was born to Harry and Minetta.....not sure why he'd be on his parents census. He seems to disappear after the 1905 census

Comment: Do you have a link to the 1905 census you reference? The one I find seems to have Harry Farson in the household of his parents in the [New York Census,1905](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:9Q97-YSRS-FJX?i=16&wc=Q69N-85D%3A42719801%2C43004401%2C44692101%3Fcc%3D1463113&cc=1463113), even thought this is well after the [1899 marriage](https://familysearch.org/search/record/results?count=20&query=%2Bgivenname%3AHarry~%20%2Bsurname%3AFarson~%20%2Bbirth_place%3A%22new%20York%22~%20%2Bbirth_year%3A1870-1880~&collection_id=1680847) to Minetta.

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to locate the 1905 link I was working from, but, the link you reference is him!  His parents are George & Mary, and he had a brother William.  1905 was the year my grandmother was born to Harry and Minetta.....not sure why he'd be on his parents census.  Any idea on how to locate arraignment results for NYC?  He seems to disappear after the 1905 census.  :-(

Comment: No, I haven't found anything either, beyond the above-mentioned newspaper article.  You may try following the other names mentioned in the case to see if they pop up later. A later census lists Minetta as married for 6 years which would correspond to the court date from the marriage date, and in the 1920 census she is listed as widowed. I was not able to find any accessible records concerning Harry's death between 1907 and 1920.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look.  I have hit a brick wall with him.  I did search on the victims name in the case was involved with....but not any of the others.   I will try that!  Thank you !!

Comment: @user2448131 I think you have enough information in your comment to post as an answer.  If anyone comes along with more information they can always add that as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for information, I find Harry Farson in the household of his parents in the [New York Census,1905](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:9Q97-YSRS-FJX?mode=g&i=16&cc=1463113), even thought this is well after the [1899 marriage](https://familysearch.org/search/record/results?count=20&query=%2Bgivenname%3AHarry~%20%2Bsurname%3AFarson~%20%2Bbirth_place%3A%22new%20York%22~%20%2Bbirth_year%3A1870-1880~&collection_id=1680847) to Minetta.  A later census lists Minetta as married for 6 years which would correspond to the time from the marriage date to the court date, and then in the 1920 census she is listed as widowed.  This gives a window of time to look for more records on Harry, but I was not able to find any accessible records concerning Harry's death between 1907 and 1920.

Concerning the referenced court case, [the article](https://bklyn.newspapers.com/clip/7485028/the_brooklyn_daily_eagle/) in the [Brooklyn Daily Eagle](https://bklyn.newspapers.com/image/57651895/?terms=Harry%2BFarson) does mention that six individuals, including Harry Farson, were arrested.  I did not find any further information, but it is possible searching the names of the other people arrested may lead to something more concerning the outcome of the case.